# Is having $G^N = I$ enough to a matrix $G$ orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

I have a matrix $G$ that is cyclic ($G^N = I$) and has determinant $\pm 1 $; is this enough to show that it is orthogonal? If not, what more could I add to make it so?

Comment: For a concrete counterexample consider
$$G=\pmatrix{-1&1\cr-1&0\cr}.$$ $G^3=I$.

Answer (score 5):

This is not sufficient. A matrix $G$ satisfying $G^N = I$ is orthogonal if and only if it is **normal**.

We say a matrix $A$ is normal when $AA^T = A^TA$.

---

Note that if a real matrix $G$ satisfies $G^N = I$, then it must also satisfy $\det(G) = \pm 1$.

Comment: perfect, thanks!

Comment: I assume that you're referring to a real matrix $G$, and are referring to real orthogonal matrices.  This extends to unitary matrices, but might not extend to complex-orthogonal matrices.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: yes, G is a real n$\times$n matrix